# Where is the Javascript library?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, computer-vision, brunch, simplecv

[SimpleCV](http://www.simplecv.org/) has released a Javascript library at [SimpleCV.js](http://demo.simplecv.org/). After looking at both their github and webpage, I still don't know how to use SimpleCV.js. How could I call on SimpleCV.js functions so that I could actually use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again .. Go to https://github.com/ingenuitas/simplecv-js

Click either of these buttons
[image: Img]